# Java - keep external collection in ordered manner

Tags: java, collections

Suppose an external collection has the following two methods: `add(BusiessObject)` to the end and `remove(BusinessObject)`. Now, I know the order of objects I want and I want to make sure that the external collection maintains that order. So, if I start with BO1, BO2, BO3, then if I remove BO2 and add it again, I want to make sure that the order will be the same.

I was thinking of keeping my list of present items, in order I want, and upon every insertion, I would clear the external list, and then add all elements from my sorted list. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have control over the external collection, I think that the solution that you proposed is the way. To keep your Java side collection ordered, you don't need to keep calling the sort method, but just use a ordered collection like [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) or [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), or any collection that implements [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) or [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), to store your data. You still need to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as @AdelBoutros said.

By the way, I'm curious about your external collection. May you say what is it? Maybe we can think in another approach if we know what it is.

Comment: Basically it is the CombinedDomainXYPlot from JFreeChart. internally it is probably using List to keep subplots, but when I remove them (i.e. hide them visually) the order goes to shit...

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with java built in [Collections sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)?

You just make your object implement the `Comparable` interface and VOILA :)

Comment: I think he is saying that he has some external third party collection which may or may not support Java collections.

Comment: That is exactly right - no control... Least to say it would make an ugly attempts to modify base classes which I do not want to attempt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the Adapter pattern would be a good fit here. In your case, create a class that implements List(or another collection that fits your ordering purpose better) and has-a external collection. Inside the methods of your adapter, you would manipulate the elements of the external collection the way you want. Even if you're using the idea you mentioned in your question, Adapter is a good design for that.

Another way would be the inverse. Extend the external collection and have a List/Queue/Set. So your client code would use this new extended class as a wrapper. Then inside your list you would obviously use the sorts and Comparable/Comparator techniques.

Comment: Hi Tiago ( greetings from Brazil ;) ). I think your suggestion is valid and I liked it, but personally I wouldn't implement an Adapter just for it... I think it is too much effort for a simple problem. Anyway, if the OP chooses to do this, here is another reference: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter

Comment: Hey! Thank you =). Well, I think it may or may not be too much effort. I would have to know his problem more deeply. Or at least take a look at some code. But, generally speaking, adapter would work quite well. Good reference by the way. I'm editing the post to change for it. ;)